# Is there a way to change a const double into an array C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, double

So, I created a simple Grade Point Average Calculation program for basically a beginner's course for C++, which I am quite new to. My assignment is now asking me to incorporate an array. I am having trouble figuring out if I can change aspects of my code like the const doubles or the doubles into an array or if I need to start over fresh for my program?

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
            cout << "Welcome to the GPA Calculation Program!";
            cout << "Lets get started.";
            const double A = 4.0
            const double A_MINUS = 3.67
            const double B_PLUS = 3.33
            const double B = 3.0
            const double B_MINUS = 2.67
            const double C_PLUS = 2.33
            const double C = 2.0
            const double C_MINUS = 1.67
            const double D = 1.0
            const double F = 0.0

            string studentName;
            string lettergrade;
            double credit;
            double calTimes = 0;
            double totalCal = 0;
            double totalCredit = 0;
            double finalGPA = 0;
            int option;
```

So, this is the part of the code that I am wondering would be changed into arrays.

Comment: Don't link to an external resource. Post the code here, in place.

Comment: Please, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please, insert code into question instead of providing a link. Btw. what's "GPA"? I've never heard about this (or it doesn't make sense in a C++ course).

Comment: Just copy-paste the code into the question. The system will only restrict you from posting too much code with too little text, it shouldn't require you to post an image. Usually somebody is nice enough to fix your code formatting if you mess up. Or see our [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and note that you can always [edit] your question.

Comment: So I tried to copy-paste the code into the question but it also tried to add an image so I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I edited my original post; GPA is Grade Point Average. I should have fully typed that out. I apologize. The program is a Calculation Program.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array in C++ like this:

```
int arr[5]; // This creates an array of 5 ints
```

And you can even assign values at initialization, like this:

```
int arr[5] = {6, 3, 2, 4, 2};
```

You can also remove the size between the square brackets and let the compiler deduce the size of the array for you, like this:

```
int arr[] = {6, 3, 2, 4, 2};
```

Either way, you can then access elements like this:

```
arr[0]; // Returns first element (6)
```

Remember that in arrays, it is not indexed from `1..size`, it is indexed from `0..(size-1)`, so if the array is 10 elements long, valid indexes would be `0..9`.

Comment: So if i wanted to assign variable to array values is that something I can do? Such as assign grade letters to their values but using an array? Does that make sense?